# cefclient.exe --enable-video-player-chromecast-support doesn't work in CEF Embedded client

Tags: chromium-embedded

I'm trying to get Chromecast to work in the CEF Embedded Client. I've built the development environment on my windows 10 machine, and the client launches when I type cefclient.exe in the command prompt.  After some googling, I found the commandline parameter of

```
cefclient.exe --enable-video-player-chromecast-support
```

but this doesn't work in either the 32 or 64 bit versions.  I've also tried

```
cefclient.exe --enable-video-player-chromecast-support --enable-media-stream --always-authorize-plugins
```

based on some other internet suggestions, without any luck.

In regular desktop chrome for windows, the "Play on TV" chromecast icon appears in the youtube video player, so I know my chromecast device is working properly.
[image: Working in Windows Desktop Chrome]

What's confusing is that there's definitely a chromecast folder in the src, so it seems like someone has implemented this, but with no clear way to make it work.

Alternatively,  is there a way to just enable all the default chrome settings so I can baseline it against Chrome for Windows Desktop?

ps: I'm using this youtube url for testing:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Yp8z2BRIgY
```

**EDIT:**
I discovered that some youtube urls can't be played in cefclient.  I'm not sure if this is a clue or not, but here's the URL:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=42M3esYyHdw
```

Comment: Why don't you search the answer or ask a question on CEF forum? Do you want us to do it for you?

Comment: @273K - I have searched the answer and I asked in the CEFGithub, and they directed me to install CEF and go from there.  I did that and went through the 12 hour build process, then went through it again to do a 64 bit build, and another that also included extensions that aren't included in the normal CEF build.  Neither of those worked with these command line parameters, so rather than spend another 12-24 hours of trying random builds I thought it was a good idea to find some help.  Do you have any useful advice, or is Google it the best you can do?

Comment: CEF forum is the first link in any search result https://magpcss.org/ceforum/index.php